# mysql Replication stalled

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am having mysql 8.0 installation with replication between 2 servers in master-master configuration. While data is being replicated from server A to server B the replication is stalled from hours. Below is the snippet for show slave status \G on server B. I am not sure on what `waiting for handler commit` means and whether its the cause of my Replication stalling

```
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
       Master_SSL_Key:
Seconds_Behind_Master: 49808
        Last_IO_Errno: 0
        Last_IO_Error:
       Last_SQL_Errno: 0
       Last_SQL_Error:Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
     Master_Server_Id: 1
     Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
            SQL_Delay: 0
  SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
  Slave_SQL_Running_State: waiting for handler commit
       Master_Retry_Count: 86400
              Master_Bind:
  Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
 Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
           Master_SSL_Crl:
```

After executing show processlist; i am getting a process that is waiting from a long time , having a wait time of 50071 and increasing

```
system user     |                               | NULL | Query       | 50071 | waiting for handler commit
```

What steps shall i take to bring my replication on track?

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION;` on both servers, please.

Comment: Both servers are running on version 8.0.13

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the same problem, absolutely no error indication but `Seconds_Behind_Master` keeps rising steadily and the `Slave_SQL_Running_State` is most of the time in `waiting for handler commit`

Answer (score 1):

That's new with 8.0.13:

> A new Performance Schema stage, waiting for handler commit, is available to detect threads going through transaction commit. Thanks to Facebook for the patch. (Bug #27855592, Bug #90417)

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90417

Suggest you file a comment with that bug report; could be that it caused a regression.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Adding:

```
   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Solved the problem for me on MySQL 8.0.13 installation.
Read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

And see also: [mysql 8.0, updates are sometimes stalling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232365/mysql-8-0-updates-are-sometimes-stalling)